# Author Profile URL

Tags: url-rewriting

I have 2 user roles. "photographer" and "subscriber"

I have set my author.php like this

```
<?php get_header(); 
    $thisauthor = get_userdata(intval($author));
    $author_user = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        ?>
     <div id="main">
     <?php
   if (user_can($author_user, 'photographer')) { 
      get_template_part( 'author', 'photographer' ); }
   else if (user_can($author_user, 'subscriber')) { 
      get_template_part( 'author', 'subscriber' ); }
     ?>
   </div><!--/main-->
     <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This is working great to show different profiles based on the user roles. However id like to change the url based on the roles.

Something like

http://xxx.xxx/subscriber/username/

http://xxx.xxx/photographer/username/

Any ideas on getting this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change all author URLs one would normally change the [author base](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite), however, since you want multiple author bases, we'll have to do things a bit differently.

There are two parts to this - The first part is getting WordPress to recognize incoming requests for your custom author pages and route them properly. To do this we'll add two new rewrite rules that take anything after a request for `subscriber/` or `photographer/` and pass that as an `author_name` to the main query. WordPress will process these as `is_author` requests, just like normal author pages.

```
function wpa_author_rewrite_rules(){

    add_rewrite_rule(
        'subscriber/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );

    add_rewrite_rule(
        'photographer/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );

}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa_author_rewrite_rules' );
```

Note that rewrite rules will need to be flushed once after adding this code so they will take effect.

The second part of this is for WordPress to generate the correct URLs when you use the API to output author URLs. Modifying WordPress output is typically done via a filter, as is the case here as well. We modify the output of functions that generate author URLs via the `author_link` filter. You'll recognize the `user_can` function in use here to check if the `$author_id` has the `subscriber` or `photographer` roles, returning custom URLs for those cases.

```
function wpa_author_link( $link, $author_id, $author_nicename ){

    if( user_can( $author_id, 'subscriber' ) ){

        return home_url( 'subscriber/' . $author_nicename . '/' );

    } elseif( user_can( $author_id, 'photographer' ) ) {

        return home_url( 'photographer/' . $author_nicename . '/' );

    }

    return $link;

}
add_filter( 'author_link', 'wpa_author_link', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Nevermind i got it working. Didnt have the last "add_filter( 'author_link', 'wpa_author_link', 10, 3 );" in.

Comment: hmm, that shouldn't happen. if you look at that function [in source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/author-template.php#L194), it calls `get_author_posts_url`, which has the `author_link` filter applied to it. do you have anything else, a plugin, that may be altering that output?

Comment: I got it working. during copy/paste i had left out the last line    add_filter( 'author_link', 'wpa_author_link', 10, 3 );

Comment: Is there a way to pull the URL from the nickname?

Comment: anyone help with this?